# How to Count Leads Of One ID Number In Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I want to count leads Of One ID Code. Does Anyone Know Formula About This?

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `SUMIFS()`.

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D,B2:B,H4)
```